# Unable to set path of polyline by passing a lat-long array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var mycenter=new google.maps.LatLng(22.352319,82.605569);
var map;
var poly1;
var ary=new Array();
function initialize()
{
    var mapprop={
        center:mycenter,
        zoom:6,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),mapprop);

    poly1=new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor: '#ff004c',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });

    poly1.setMap(map);
    testmarker();
}

function showmarker(ary)
{
    var path=poly1.getPath();
    map.setZoom(15);
    path.push(ary);
    poly.setPath(path);  // this line doesn't execute
    alert(ary);    
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
```

Here I am trying to set path of polyline through function `showmarker()`. The array `ary` contains lat-long values. I want to display polyline with the values in the `ary`. The `ary` contains values like the following `[(lat,long),(lat,long),...]`. I'm not able to display the polyline by passing this array in its path. `poly1.setPath(path)` is not executing at all.

Comment: In the above code "poly.setPath(path)" is "poly1.setPath(path)"

Comment: please edit your question to fix that.  What is `testmarker`?

Comment: Sorry, that was left there by mistake, testmarker() does'nt call anything.

Comment: please edit your question to fix that as well.

Comment: <script>
function testmarker()
{
var ar = <?php echo json_encode($a) ?>;
// alert(ary);
showmarker(ary);
// var path=poly.getPath();



// path.push(ar);

// poly.setPath(path);
// alert(ar);
}
</script>

Testmarker is being used to call showmarker with the array of co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't push the path(`ary`) directly, it's an array, but a polygon-path consists of LatLngs.

You must iterate over the items and push the single items(LatLngs)

```js
function initialize() {

  var mapprop = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(22, 82),
      zoom: 6
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"), mapprop),
    poly1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map,
      path: [new google.maps.LatLng(22, 82.4),
        new google.maps.LatLng(21.7, 83)
      ]
    });
  showmarker([new google.maps.LatLng(22, 82),
      new google.maps.LatLng(21, 83),
      new google.maps.LatLng(22.5, 81),
      new google.maps.LatLng(20, 80)
    ],
    poly1
  );
}

function showmarker(
  path, //LatLng-Array
  poly //target-polygon
) {

  path.forEach(function(coord) {
    //note: getPath returns a reference,
    //you may add a point directly
    poly.getPath().push(coord);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapholder {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="mapholder"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

var mycenter=new google.maps.LatLng(22.352319,82.605569);
var map;
var poly1;
var ary=new Array();
function initialize()
{
var mapprop={
center:mycenter,
zoom:6,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),mapprop);

// var polyoptions={ strokeColor: '#000000',
    // strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    // strokeWeight: 3
  // };
  poly1=new google.maps.Polyline({
  strokeColor: '#ff004c',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3

  });

  poly1.setMap(map);




}

function showmarker(ary)
{

var path=poly1.getPath();
map.setZoom(15);
var i;
for(i=0;i<ary.length;i++)
{
path.push(ary[i]);

}
poly1.setPath(path);




}




google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
</script>
```

Thanks Dr.Molle. It worked good like this.